# Switch email service providers from current host - terminology

Tags: email, dns, hosting, terminology

I posted this question on webmasters.stackexchange.com but no reply, so I thought I'd try here. I have a feeling it's not appropriate for this site but I'd like some answers :)

---

I've got hosting services provided by FatCow. They use SquirrelMail for their email handler, which has an abysmal frontend, has a low mailbox storage limit, and apparently Fatcow doesn't allow remote access to change a password.

As a result, the webmaster has to change passwords explicitly for the user - ridiculous. Anyway, enough complaining.

What I'd like to do is use the same domain with a different provider, but I don't know the words to begin my search. Provider? Hosting? Client? How do I get started here?

I'd also accept a good recommendation for a provider (or whatever the word is) that solves the above problem description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to do your email through your domain server. So just google 'email hosting.' For example, check out [google business email](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/smb/email.html#utm_campaign=en&utm_source=en-ha-na-us-bk&utm_medium=ha&utm_term=google%20business%20email). Google does all the heavy lifting and you create email addresses for whatever domain you own.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for an *email provider*. This provider needs to offer services for custom domains (i.e. not limited to their own @hotmail.com or whatever it happens to be). You need to sign up with them, configure that you would like them to handle email for your `example.com` domain, then change the DNS configuration for `example.com` and point the `MX` record at your new email provider. That means you need to have the authority/permission/possibility to change your DNS records. If you bought the domain through your host, they *may* not allow you to do that, in which case you may have to look into a domain transfer or into hosting your DNS elsewhere.

Google Apps for Business is a decent example of an email provider and is free for "small businesses". They offer the Gmail interface customized for your domain, among other things.

Comment: Sorry @deceze mrtsherman was just that much faster.  Boy's got lightning in them fingers.  +1 for your effort though, cheers, it's very helpful. :)

Comment: The fun part is that nobody said anything for almost an hour, then two answers within the same minute... :o)